# Is an EF query with .Include query slower than getting the child objects in separate calls?

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

I found a piece of code that gets thousands of entities from a database (to populate a cache). These entities have many many child objects connected to it, which turns the query into something rather huge.

One could do `.Include("ChildObject")` and `.Include("ChildObject.ChildObjectOfChildObject")` ++ but instead, the author of this code, has chosen to load all of these sub objects in their own queries, and later match on ID, and fill this data into a wrapper (In other words, they end up like objects that has all of the data you would get with .Include())

Is there a performance gain to this? As I see it the operations done are the same, the only difference is that the join is done in C# code in a for loop (when looping over all of the parent entities). I always thought that the database was quickest and most optimized at doing datamanipulation, and parts of this datamanipulation in .NET would be slower...

Comment: Kinda, but not really... My question is about loading parts of the object graph in many small queries and then matching it serverside... instead of using Lazy, Explicit or Eager loading...

Comment: That depends. Usually, loading with Include is faster, because you do whole thing in one database query. However, query generated for that _might_ be inefficient (say not use some indexes you have), and separate queries might use indexes well and so might be faster.

Comment: So this basically depends on how the indexes in the database is set up, and how SQL Server's execution plan ends up being? - And no general rule of thumb that could guide me in a direction?

Comment: Yes, on indexes and which query exactly is generated by EF to load all your entities in one go. If you care about that - log query generated with includes, then log queries generated by separate calls, then inspect their execution plans.